# service properties in CAS client

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

I wanted to connect one of my web apps with CAS server. I successfully created my CAS server also with SSL setting. but there is an ambiguity when I wanted to set up my CAS client.

In spring web site there is a bean like this which they say we should initialize and create it.

```xml
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="https://localhost:8443/cas-sample/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
</bean>
```

The problem here I can't understand what is "service" and what URL it is referred to? I mean in my web app, what the value of "service" should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Spring Security 3 book:

> The service property indicates to CAS the service to which the user will be
>   authenticated.

For example: `https://localhost:8443/your-web-application/j_spring_cas_security_check`